# How to find duplicates values in list Python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I was wondering how can I know if when a user inputs a value, that value already exists in a list.

For example;

```
lis = ['foo', 'boo', 'hoo']
```

user inputs:

```
'boo'
```

Now my question is how can I tell the user this value already exists inside the list.

Comment: Your question is more *avoiding* duplicates in a list. If you don't care about order, you could also use a `set`, which, if you attempt to add a duplicate, it ignores it.

Comment: oh yes... the set function... I am a bit unfamiliar with its use.. but I have indeed seen it in action.

Comment: It's not a function, but [a full-blown data-type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) along with `int`, `dict`, `list`, and `str`.

Comment: oh wow... so its more than what I expected for it to be ! Thanks NickT for the great info !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in):

```
>>> lis = ['foo', 'boo', 'hoo']
>>> 'boo' in lis
True
>>> 'zoo' in lis
False
```

You can also use `lis.index` which will return the index of the element.

```
>>> lis.index('boo')
1
```

If the element is not found, it will raise `ValueError`:

```
>>> lis.index('zoo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 'zoo' is not in list
```

**UPDATE**

As Nick T commented, if you don't care about order of items, you can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set):

```
>>> lis = {'foo', 'boo', 'hoo'}  # set literal  == set(['foo', 'boo', 'hoo'])
>>> lis.add('foo')  # duplicated item is not added.
>>> lis
{'boo', 'hoo', 'foo'}
```

Comment: Thanks alot friend ! This helped alot.. and clear some ideas up. :)

Answer (score 4):

One more way you can do is use collections :-

```
import collections
lis = ['foo', 'boo', 'hoo']
# Now if user inputs boo
lis.append('boo')
print [x for x, y in collections.Counter(lis).items() if y > 1]
# Now it will print the duplicate value in output:-
boo
```

But the above one is not efficient. So for make it efficient use set as falsetru indicates in the answer:-

```
totalList= set()
uniq = []
for x in lis:
    if x not in totalList:
        uniq.append(x)
        totalList.add(x)
```

Comment: Thank you Brother Hussain, that is a very nice example. The second example is short and concise, really good.